# Pass a label as parameter to a function

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

I am creating a utility to insert few records into SQL after performing some calculations. I am using a background worker to stop the app from going into a non-responding state. As the process works I need to change few label values for which I use a delegate. Is it possible to pass my label as parameter to a function which has the delegate so I can re-use some of this code?

Below is the function I use to change to change value of label2. For label3 I have used another function that's nearly identical. Is it possible to create a function that accepts label as parameter so that I can pass control name and the required message, and it does the updating for me?

Here is my code for changing label2:

```
public void changelabel(string msg)
{
    if (label2.InvokeRequired)
        label2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            label2.Text = msg;
        }));
    else
        label2.Text = msg;
}
```

Comment: What label? Windows forms? WPF? ASP.Net?

Comment: sorry have retagged it to winforms

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the relevant code you've written.

Comment: @CAbbott posted the code.. thanks :-)

Comment: Have you tried using a Label as a function parameter? Did it work?

Comment: @MrLister no i didnot ..was not sure whether its possible. :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your labels are just fields of your form, as long as you don't actually call methods or set properties on them, you can pass them around as you like:

```
public void ChangeLabel(string msg, Label label) {
    if (label.InvokeRequired)
        label.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
            label.Text = msg;
        }));
    else
        label.Text = msg;
}
```

Comment: Oops, accidentally modified your answer instead of mine. Sorry about that. The "edit" buttons looked so similar... ;-) In fact, I'll just remove my answer since it's covered by yours (+1, btw).